# to increase the reading and writing/printing speed of data from Arduino Nano to Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: arduino-nano

In my project, I have to read the input pin number(send by RPi), where 8 sensors are attached to Arduino Nano, after reading Arduino Nano send the real-time values of all sensors through serial USB communication. All is fine, but my problem is that I need to speed up the sending of data since it takes to long to read from Rasberry pi.
I put the delay of 70 milliseconds but if I try to reduce more than that, I encounter a problem i.e data overwrites. My baud rate is 115200.
Kindly help me with the code to make it fast.

```
int analogInputPin;
float voltage;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // if any data on the serial port are available
  // read it and try to update the analogInputPin
  // based on the number that was read on the serial  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    analogInputPin = Serial.parseInt();
  }

  // read the analog value:
  int analogInputPinValue = analogRead(analogInputPin);
  voltage=(5./1023.)*analogInputPinValue;

  // print the results to the serial port:
  // the output should have the following form: INPUTPIN:VALUE
  // followed by a newline character
  Serial.print(analogInputPin);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.println("");

  // wait 50 milliseconds before the next loop
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Look at the source code for Serial.parseInt(). Consider reading to a buffer instead.

Comment: Don't use `parseInt`. Ever. It's rancid. Read serial *properly* : https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` reads digits and stops after a non-digit characters occurs or the function times out because no next characters arrives. The timeout is at default 1 second. So this is where you loose time.

Simplest solution for your code is to send some non-digit character after the number sent from Raspberry. This will terminate parseInt immediately. Usual is to send a new line character. It will separate the numbers nice if you debug the communication with prints to serial terminal.

Not a very good option, but I mention it, is to set the timeout of blocking read functions like the `parseInt` to a smaller time with `Serial.setTimeout(ms)`.

To really speed up the communication you would send the numbers in binary form and not as text like you do now.